# There are no logon servers available to service the login request

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

On my home network I setup a laptop running windows server 2003 as a dns server and domain controller. I was able to join the domain on my PC, however if I try to login to windows with a domain account on my PC it says:

**There are no logon servers available to service the login request**

If I'm logged into my normal windows account then I can ping the domain just fine, however I noticed when I try to switch users it shuts down my internet connection, which is most likely why it then says that it can't find the logon server. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that your wireless connection does not come up until you logon - which might be the result of some 3rd party configuration software taking over from the "Windows Wireless Zero Configuration" service.

My suggestion would be to uninstall any software that might be doing so, and then reconfigure your wireless network connection with windows. The connection should then come up when the computer starts, allowing you to logon to the domain as normal.

Comment: I'm using windows to control my wireless, although it's Windows 7 so it's not called the wireless zero configuration service anymore. I can actually login as a domain user if I reboot the PC and login directly as the domain user. It just doesn't work if I first login as a windows user and then try to switch and login as a domain user. Not sure why this makes a difference, any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I don't know what led me to assume you were using XP! In that case this seems like a very odd issue - something must be messing around with your network connections, possibly at logon? Another possible cause is that Windows 7 requires you so specify the domain explicitly either using the username@domain.name format or DOMAIN\username.

Comment: I'm specifying the domain explicitly. Thanks for the help though, since I have a work-around (rebooting) I can work with it.